# Combine and manipulate querysets based on if object in one is not in another

Tags: python, django, object, django-queryset

For some reason I cannot figure out the best way to do this.

I can merge them, get the difference, etc - but can't figure out how to merge both query sets based on values, and then assign a different value after they're merged.

I have two QuerySets:

```
query_set_a = Reports.objects.filter(
        agent=report.profile.agent_code, 
        product='product_a', 
        date__range=(report_range_start, report_range_end),
        prem_submitted__gt=0).order_by('date')

query_set_b = Reports.objects.filter(
        agent=report.profile.agent_code, 
        product='product_b', 
        date__range=(report_range_start, report_range_end),
        prem_submitted__gt=0).order_by('date')
```

If you consider the following:

```
{% for each in query_set_a %} 

[{{ each.date|date:"m-d" }} - {{ each.activated }}],

{% endfor %}

{% for each in query_set_b %} 

[{{ each.date|date:"m-d" }} - {{ each.activated }}],

{% endfor %}
```

Which outputs correctly:

```
query_set_1 output
[08-01 - 2], [08-02 - 2], [08-03 - 1], [08-06 - 1], [08-07 - 1], [08-10 - 13], [08-13 - 2]
query_set_2 output
[08-01 - 21], [08-02 - 23], [08-03 - 18], [08-06 - 17], [08-07 - 5], [08-09 - 2], [08-10 - 30], [08-13 - 13], [08-15 - 4],
```

How would I take values that are in `query_set_2 output` and add them to `query_set_1`, but set `query_set_1.activated` to null? Such that `query_set_1` would look like:

```
[08-01 - 2], [08-02 - 2], [08-03 - 1], [08-06 - 1], [08-07 - 1], [08-09 - null], [08-10 - 13], [08-13 - 2], [08-15 - null]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use case when like this.

```
Reports.objects.filter(
    agent=report.profile.agent_code, 
    product__in=['product_a', 'product_b'], 
    date__range=(report_range_start, report_range_end),
    prem_submitted__gt=0).annotate(
         new_activate=models.Case(
               models.When(product='product_a', then='activated')
               default=None
               output_field=models.IntegerField()
         )
    ).order_by('date')
```

Comment: Thanks! So that combines the two querysets, which is helpful, and adds the new_activate field to anything that's `product_b`. What I'm attempting to do is, whenever there's a result for `product_b` with no result for `product_a` on the same date, then add an object with the date from `product_b`, and set `activated = null` - if that makes sense. So there'd be equal results for both `product_a` and `product_b`. Any pointers if that explanation makes sense? `product_a` is always a subset of `product_b`, with different `activated` amounts, and I'm trying to make them equal lengths.

Comment: Are you want to group result by `date`?

Comment: I want to order by `date`. Each item has a unique date, so there won't be two `product_b`s with the same date so I assume I don't have to group them. But there might not be an entry for `product_a` on the same day as `product_b`. So I'd want to add a `product_a` with `activated = null` on the date that does have a `product_b` but doesn't have a `product_a`, like in the last example output in the question. Does that make sense? I guess I could loop through and compare them, and add to `product_a` results if there's no matching date for `product_b`?

Comment: is there both `product_a` and `product_b` exists for one date?

Comment: In some cases, yes. There will always be a `product_b` if there's a `product_a`, but there won't always be a `product_a` if there's a `product_b`.

Comment: you can filter only `product_b` and with a case filter calculate activate field value